# Puppeteer: stop verbose console spam

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I've started Puppeteer to automate webpage information scaping.
One issue I have is, the script outputs into console every piece of data received. How do I stop that? Checked documentation and googled for answers, but got nothing.

I want to get rid of this useless flood and see only my own console.log() outputs:

[image: console spammed]

My example code:

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    devtools: true,
    dumpio: false,
    slowMo: 250,
    defaultViewport: { width: 600, height: 800 },
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?source=auth_switcher");
  await page.waitFor('input[name="username"]');
  await page.type('input[name="username"]', "NewUser");
  await browser.close();

  console.log("Iam done!");
})();
```

Comment: I created a new folder, ran `npm init -y` to create a Node project, ran `npm i -S puppeteer` to install Puppeteer, pasted your code in an `index.js` file, and ran `node index` to run it. Result: the script worked, and there were no log at all in the terminal appart from your `Iam done!`  Please provide enough information for us to reproduce the issue

Comment: Same for me as for _blex_. Nothing verboose in the terminal, not even if I set dumpio to true. You seems to have another node process running at the same time that is logging these. Please provide more context.

Comment: Hmm, thanks for your input. I'm executing the script in VSCode through a 'Quick Run' button (extension Code Runner) - the extension might be appending verbose log arg to node process when executing my js. Tried by directly running 'node script.js' and there is indeed no log spam. Thanks and sorry to trouble you.

Answer (score 1):

VSCode extension Code Runner was responsible for enabling verbose console output for script executed through it. Running the script with 'node script.js' yields expected behaviour.